# Click inside click function causing alert message showing more than once - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is little hard to explain so i have made a `jsfiddle`. The problem is that. when i click on `<li>` first time, i get 1 alert message.

Now i again click on any `<li>`, now what i am getting 2 alerts.

First click on any `input field --> then li --> then input field again --> then li again.`

**Markup:**

```
<input type='text' class='InputField'>
<input type='text' class='InputField2'>
<input type='text' class='InputField3'>
<div class="ranges FullBoxControl" style='display:none'>
    <ul>
        <li>This Month</li>
        <li>This Year</li>
        <li>Last 5 Years</li>
        <li>Last 10 Years</li>
        <li>Custom Range</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Script code:**

```
$(".InputField").click(function()
{
    $('.FullBoxControl').show();
    $('.FullBoxControl').click(function()
    {
        alert('Greetings');
    });
});

$(".InputField2").click(function()
{
    $('.FullBoxControl').show();
    $('.FullBoxControl').click(function()
    {
        alert('Greetings');
    });
});

$(".InputField3").click(function()
{
    $('.FullBoxControl').show();
    $('.FullBoxControl').click(function()
    {
        alert('Greetings');
    });
});
```

[`JsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/x85A6/3/)

Ask me if you people didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x85A6/8/). Each time you click in input field, it binds click event, so it is necessary to put repetitive code in common function and unbind click event, before binding click event again.

```
$(".InputField").click(function()
{
    fullbox();
});

$(".InputField2").click(function()
{
    fullbox();
});

$(".InputField3").click(function()
{
    fullbox();
});
function fullbox(){
    $('.FullBoxControl').show();
    $('.FullBoxControl').unbind("click");
    $('.FullBoxControl').click(function()
    {
        alert('Greetings');
    });
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same thing. This would probably be your best bet

Answer (score 1):

Use `unbind` to remove the double event handler

```
$(".InputField").click(function()
{ 
    $('.FullBoxControl').show();
    $('.FullBoxControl').unbind();
    $('.FullBoxControl').click(function()
    {
        alert('Greetings');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x85A6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to see if you have already attached the click event:

http://jsfiddle.net/x85A6/6/

```
var eventAttached = false;

$(".InputField").click(function() {
    if (!eventAttached) {
        $('.FullBoxControl').show();
        $('.FullBoxControl').click(function(){
            alert('Greetings');
        });
        eventAttached = true;
    }
});

$(".InputField2").click(function() {
    if (!eventAttached) {
        $('.FullBoxControl').show();
        $('.FullBoxControl').click(function(){
            alert('Greetings');
        });
        eventAttached = true;
    }
});

$(".InputField3").click(function() {
     if (!eventAttached) {
        $('.FullBoxControl').show();
        $('.FullBoxControl').click(function(){
            alert('Greetings');
        });
        eventAttached = true;
    }
});
```